# ojdbc14 jar oracle 10g java java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, oracle, jar, oracle10g

hello people i m stuck with the following error

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource
Exception in thread "main" Message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:10.43.210.170:1521:radem
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.DBcnx.main(DBcnx.java:25)
```

i know it was posted before and i checked the answers .. tried to put the driver (ojdbc14 . jar ) in the same path as the class but still the same error ..im kind of an amateur in java so basically i have no idea what i m doing or what i should do ..my code is the following :

```
    package com.test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBcnx {

//connection
static   String url="jdbc:thin:oracle:10.43.210.170:1521:radem";
static         String user="USER1";
static         String pass="radem";
static         String driver="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"; 


static Connection con;
static boolean isconnect ;

public static void main(String args[] ) throws SQLException  
{
    isconnect=Connect(url,user,pass,driver); 
    String select = "select * from dual"; 
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(select);
    while( result.next())
    {
     System.out.println(result.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
    stmt.close();

}


public static boolean Connect(String url,String user,String pass, String driver)
    {


    try{
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
            System.out.println("chargement driver");
             }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Chargement drivers echoue\n"+e); 
            }

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            System.out.println("\nConnection a la base etablie");

        }
        catch(Exception evt)
        { 
                System.out.println("Message: "+ evt.getMessage()); ;
                return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

any help is the most welcome .. thank you !

Comment: Have you added the .jar file to your project?

Comment: Your code claims to use the URL `jdbc:thin:oracle:` but the error message says you are using `jdbc:odbc:`. So apparently the code you are showing us is not the code you are running. And why are you using this outdated driver version? `ojdbc14.jar` is intended for Java **1.4**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your driver class name is incorrect.  It should be oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

You return a boolean flag to indicate if connection was successful, but you ignore it.